# CMake Cross compile Arm64 error “unrecognised command line option ‘-msse’”

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, arm64

I am trying to cross-compile openCV for an Arm64 linux platform and am getting the following errors

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognised command line option ‘-msse’; did you mean ‘-fdse’?
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognised command line option ‘-msse2’
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognised command line option ‘-msse3’
```

I understand that the -msse flags are not compatible with arm64, yet when I generate my makefile from CMake, these flags are include.
My CMake command is

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/cuda-10/bin/nvcc \
      -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/opt/l4t-gcc-toolchain-64-bit-32-7.1/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc \
      -DCUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/cuda-10/targets/aarch64-linux/include \
      -DCUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-10/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcudart.so \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
      -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
      -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="6.2" \
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules/ \
      -D ENABLE_CXX11=ON ..
```

I am building on linux ubuntu 18.4.
How to do I tell CMake that the platform is Arm64?
Thanks

Comment: Setting up a cross toolchain can be tricky. For example are you sure you have a CUDA GPU on your ARM architecture? Maybe it is easier to use the linux package manager on ARM to install OpenCV without cross compile?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it's an Nvidia Jetson TX2 board so has a CUDA GPU. I can build on this but it takes a long time. I would like to be able to cross-compile to improve build speed, not just to build Open CV but for our application which uses CUDA and OpenCV, and takes a long time to build on our Arm64 platform.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, the missing flag I was looking for was

```
-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/aarch64-gnu.toolchain.cmake
```